# Unable to exclude DataSourceAutoConfiguration class while running fat jar from cmd

Tags: spring-boot, fatjar, spring-autoconfiguration

Below is my spring boot main class configuration :

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfigurationProperties
public class MainClass{

}
```

When i am running this spring boot using intellij, it doesn't throw any error but after i had exported the fat jar using the following :

build.gradle >>>

```
jar{
   manifest{
      attributes{
         //main class
      }
   }
   from{
      configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect{it.isDirectory()? it : zipTree(it)}

   }
}
```

the cmd output says :

```
The following classes could not be excluded because they are not auto-configurable classes:
    - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
```

Can someone please help me understand what I am missing while running through cmd?

I tried excluding "META-INF/*.SF", "META-INF/*.DSA" , "META-INF/*.RSA" while creating the fat jar but the issue still persists.

Comment: Remove your `jar` task (and I assume you have the spring boot gradle plugin). Re-run `./gradlew build` to have a proper jar. Also why do you need the exclude? If you define the datasource yourself it will backoff anyway, if there are no properties and JDBC drivers/JDBC classes it will backoff as well.

Comment: I do not want to have any datasource configurations in my project. I want to exclude database presence all the way. I don't have any JDBC drivers/classes in my project.

Comment: Also i'll need a fat jar because my project depends on some other libraries.

Comment: Spring BOot **will generate a fat jar** you don't need to do anything for it, the fact that you do is the actual problem. If you don't have JDBC nor configuration what is the point of excluding it? It doesn't prevent anyone from using your app to provide additional configuration classes to still provide a `Datasource`.

Comment: I excluded it because I was getting entityManagerFactory issues. It was not able to create dataSource bean.

Comment: For JPA you need a Datasource hence you included JPA but don't want a datasource? That seems weird to me.

Comment: man i have no jpa dependenices

Comment: Well if there aren't there would be no JPA configuration (as that depends) on the JPA api). Just out of curiosity could you post your full `build.gradle`? Nonetheless you don't need your jar task as Spring Boot will already build the fatjar for you so there is no need for that. But I'm curious to why you would even need the exclude as things should backoff automatically.

Comment: I can't really post the whole config as it is not availble in external network though I believe it is coming from the dependencies (libraries). I have two library projects.

Comment: 1. a domain library which depends on dedup library and the dedup library which has jpa dependencies 2. a exec-common library which has jpa dependencies

Comment: Then that is the problem, that will pull in some JPA dependencies which triggers JPA autoconfiguration. Instead of excluding the autoconfiguration you could try to globally exclude the JPA api/hibernate classes from being included in your artifact because you obviously don't need them? Anyway using the Sprig Boot plugin should resolve your issue (as mentioned before).

Comment: How can I globally exclude? I cannot modify the libraries.

Comment: You can add global excludes in your own `build.gradle` to exclude dependencies. I assume those are pulling in the JPA dependencies. But that is besied the point, your problem is already solved by using the Spring Boot plugin instead of your own jar task.

Comment: exclude respective dependencies worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to build a fatjar yourself. Spring Boot already handles that for you.

Remove your custom jar task and make sure you have the Spring Boot plugin in yuour list of plugins.

```
plugins {
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.1'
}
```

Or whatever your version is.

Then when running `./gradlew build` or `gradle build` the resulting artifact will already be a fatjar and runnable jar. You don't need to do any additional work for that.